# How to add a header file in Visual Studio 2013, C++

Tags: c++, build, compilation, header

I use Visual Studio 2013 to build a program. I have got some problems...
a) an error:

```
c:\users\wojciech\desktop\cryingdamson 0.3.6 (8.60) v8.2 source\otpch.h(28): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xmlmemory.h': No such file or directory
```

My  code:

```
#include <libxml/xmlmemory.h>
```

I have included that file in Visual Studio 2013 to header files and I have even it at libxml folder. I can not still build solution (compile) because of that error.

Please help me, I am new to Visual Studio. I have tried to add xmlmemory.h file to project properties, but it seems that it doesn't see the file.

Okay, in folder "c:\users\wojciech\my documents/visual studio 2013/projects/consoleapplication3" there is a file named MainProject.sln, which type is microsoft visual solution. In the same folder I have added libxml folder and in the folder I have put xmlmemory.h. The problem is I still can not compile the program.

I use windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to add the parent Folder of libxml to the include path. Say if the Folder structure Looks like

- some_project

  - include

    - libxml

      - xmlmemory.h
- ...

you Need to add the include Directory to the include path

Comment: I just add this http://blog.gockelhut.com/2009/11/visual-studio-2010-property-sheets-and.html to your answer. op sounds like someone that should read a few lines about libraries/includes

Comment: Okay, in folder "c:\users\wojciech\my documents/visual studio 2013/projects/consoleapplication3" there is a file named MainProject.sln, which type is microsoft visual solution. In the same folder I have added libxml folder and in the folder I have put xmlmemory.h. The problem is I still can not compile the program.

Comment: For external libraries I recommend adding the path to the library to the include path (in the Project Settings)

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `xmlmemory.h`? Of `#include <.../libxml/xmlmemory.h>` try a complete path in the `...` part.

The path `libxml/xmlmemory.h` is in fact `./libxml/xmlmemory.h` where `./` means the location of your workspace.

===============Next is added according to your comment==========================

Just using `#include "..\libxml\xmlmemory.h"` would compile. So your workspace path is therefore `c:\users\wojciech\my documents/visual studio 2013/projects/consoleapplication3`. Under your workspace there should be a folder `MainProject` where your existed source files are located. So `.\` means the path `c:\users\wojciech\my documents\visual studio 2013\projects\consoleapplication3\MainProject`.

Note that you should use `\` other than `/` to represent your file hierarchy in your project and that you should use `"xxx.h"`  other than `<xxx.h>`.

You can also use this method: open `VIEW->Property Manager`, right click on `MainProject` and open `Properties`, in `C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories`, add your folder `libxml` to it. Then all files under your `libxml` folder would become a part of your solution. You can just use `#include "xmlmemory.h>"` to make it compile.

Either way is supposed to compile.

Comment: Okay, in folder "c:\users\wojciech\my documents/visual studio 2013/projects/consoleapplication3" there is a file named MainProject.sln, which type is microsoft visual solution. In the same folder I have added libxml folder and in the folder I have put xmlmemory.h. The problem is I still can not compile the program.

Comment: @waqmaz93 I've revised my answer. Add your comment if there are still problems.

Comment: First of all I want to thank You for the answer. It is cool that a foreign can do something for a foreign, so thank you so much! =) What can I do for You? But I have one more question. How to make it working using this "<" and this ">" instead of " " ". Thanks.. Best Regards!

Comment: Just use google.com, man.  For your question, have a look at [#include Directive (C/C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4.aspx) or [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include “filename”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

Comment: @waqmaz93 If this do help you, please accept it as your answer.

Comment: It doesn't help me. I do not know where and how to put a folder libxml to works it correctly using <>.

Comment: But that was not what your question ask!  And for your 'one-more' question, please reference to my comment..the two links...you cannot...only files in standard library can use < >...files you yourself defined should always use " "...